# Precise informations in text file to excel columns using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

[enter link description here][1]I'm trying to search specific words in this text file in order to output it's line content in excel columns. The text file contains multiple sections. I'm able to output the first section of my text file but for some reasons I can't define a loop so I could retrieve every section of the file.

My code so far :

```
Sub test()
Dim myFile As String, text As String, textline As String, DDC As Integer, DDR As Integer, DDP As Integer, ADC As Integer, i As Integer, SE As Integer, SP As Integer, SG As Integer, j As Integer, v As Integer

myFile = "C:\Users\Seb\Desktop\text2.txt"
Open myFile For Input As #1
Do Until EOF(1)
Line Input #1, textline
 text = text & textline
Loop
Close #1

i = 1

    DDC = InStr(text, "Date de calcul")
    DDR = InStr(text, "Date de retraite")
    ADC = InStr(text, "Âge à la date du calcul")
    SE = InStr(text, "Service d'emploi")
    SP = InStr(text, "Service de participation")
    SG = InStr(text, "Salaire gagné")
    Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = Mid(text, DDC, 14)
    Cells(i + 1, 2).Value = Mid(text, DDC + 36, 10)
    Cells(i + 2, 1).Value = Mid(text, DDR, 16)
    Cells(i + 2, 2).Value = Mid(text, DDR + 36, 10)
    Cells(i + 3, 1).Value = Mid(text, ADC, 23)
    Cells(i + 3, 2).Value = Mid(text, ADC + 36, 6)
    Cells(i + 4, 1).Value = Mid(text, SE, 16)
    Cells(i + 4, 2).Value = Mid(text, SE + 36, 6)
    Cells(i + 5, 1).Value = Mid(text, SP, 24)
    Cells(i + 5, 2).Value = Mid(text, SP + 36, 6)
    For v = 0 To 10
    j = v * 228
    Cells(v + 7, 1).Value = Mid(text, SG + j, 24) + Mid(text, SG + 64 + j,     10) + "/ " + Mid(text, SG + 77 + j, 10)
    Cells(v + 7, 2).Value = Mid(text, SG + 103 + j, 10)
    Next v

End Sub
```

An exemple of my text file is available here:  http://txt.do/5j2dq

As I mentioned before, I'm only able to output section 1 in excel. What my code should be in order to retrieve every sections of my text file?

Comment: How about going back to your previous question?

Answer (score 0):

After you have covered each section, simply remove the covered part from your `text` string, so that in the next iteration e.g. `InStr(text, "Date 1")` will find the `Date 1` line of the next section.

```
Do While True
    DDC = InStr(text, "Date 1")
    If DDC = 0 Then
        ' no more sections - exit loop
        Exit Do
    End If
    DDR = InStr(text, "Date 2")
    ADC = InStr(text, "Age")
    ' ......

    Next v

    ' remove the section that was just handled
    text = Mid(text, SG + 30)
Loop
```

Comment: I don't understand how this part of the code can remove a section                  ' remove the section that was just handled
    text = Mid(text, SG + 30)

Comment: @mckaymental: simply try it out while stepping through the code. `SG` points at the begin of the "Salary" line, `SG + 30` is about its end. `Mid()` without the 3rd argument takes everything of the string, starting at the 2nd argument up to the end.

Comment: It works but the first data I get are erase by the second set in Excel. Also I have a lot of this kind of section in my file, how can I get them all ? I put an extrat of my real file here http://txt.do/5j2dq

Answer (score 0):

If you bring the TXT file in as Data ► External Data ► From Text, you can set period as an *Other* delimiter (with *Treat consecutive delimiters as one* being True).

```
Sub Import_Text()
    Dim c As Long, myFile As String

    myFile = "C:\Users\Seb\Desktop\text.txt"

    With Worksheets("Sheet9")   '<~~set this worksheet reference properly!

        With .QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & myFile, _
            Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
            .Name = "TXT"
            .FieldNames = True
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
            .TextFilePlatform = 437
            .TextFileStartRow = 1
            .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
            .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
            .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = True
            .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
            .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
            .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
            .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
            .TextFileOtherDelimiter = "."
            .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1)
            .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With

        'these will cleanup (trim) the results
        For c = 1 To 2
            With .Columns(c)
                .TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(1), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
                               FieldInfo:=Array(0, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
            End With
        Next c

    End With
End Sub
```

There are two final [Range.TextToColumns method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193593.aspx) with the `xlFixedWidth` option that simply trim off any rogue leading/railing spaces from the results.